# Looping through Vehicles API data, to loop through that to get individual Vehicle data - getting Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-httpclient

I am relatively new to Angular (more experienced with older version of Angular). I have two APIs, one is "/vehicles" and another is "/vehicle/{id}".

I get the "/vehicles" data and I loop through, match the IDs and then do another API call to "/vehicle/{id}" to get additional data for that particular vehicle and then create a new data object.

This all works but I get a console log error of `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` so I'm assuming the template is looking for this data before it's finished getting the data (because the page loads as it should but can't get rid of this error).

This is the part of HTML issue I get - `<h2>{{ car.id | uppercase }} {{ car.modelYear | uppercase }}</h2>`

```
cars: Cars[] = [];

this.restApi.getCars().subscribe((cars: any = []) => {
  cars.forEach((car: any = {}, i: string) => {
    this.restApi.getCar(car.id).subscribe((c: any = {}) => {
      if (car.id === c.id) {
        this.cars[i] = {...c, ...car};
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here are the console logs of data

```
cars = [
  {id: "xe", modelYear: "k17", url: "/api/vehicle/xe", media: Array(1)}
  {id: "xf", modelYear: "k17", url: "/api/vehicle/xf", media: Array(1)}
  {id: "xj", modelYear: "k16", url: "/api/vehicle/xj", media: Array(1)}
]

car = {
  description: "Premium luxury saloon, spacious and beautiful yet powerfully agile."
  id: "xj"
  meta: {passengers: 5, drivetrain: Array(2), bodystyles: Array(2), emissions: {…}}
  price: "£50,000"
}
```

My Rest Api service

```
getCars() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiURL}/vehicles/`)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

getCar(id: string) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiURL}/vehicle/${id}`)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should console log cars and put content to question

Comment: In which line does the id error appear?

Comment: You should edit your question to show the API response.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm the error appears from the HTML file (the car.id part) - it's showing the data on my template correctly but still see the error for some reason anyways.

Comment: @HienNguyen
I've added a console log section to the question, thanks

Comment: @riazosama I've added a console log section to the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful when chaining observable subscribe. A better approach is to use rxjs operator like `mergeMap` to combine multiple http cals

```
this.restApi.getCars().pipe(
   mergeMap((cars) => {
     return cars.map( car => this.restApi.getCar(car.id).pipe(
        map(carDetail => Object.assign(car, carDetail))
     ));
   })
).subscribe((cars: any = []) => {
  this.cars = cars
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I am seeing 'map' does not exist on type 'Object', do I need to assign a type to cars?

Comment: So I'm assuming that your usage of angular httpclient is wrong. Can you verify it ? `http.get<Cars[]>` will correct typescript typings

Answer (score 0):

You are right here in assuming, that angular is attempting to access the data in cars array, before the service call is getting completed, to render the template. As the service is yet to return a response, angular gets undefined for all the child elements of car array.

One way to get rid of this problem would be to loop over the cars array instead of accessing the child element by specifying the index number(which I'm unsure if you're doing or not) as below -

```
<div *ngFor=" car in cars">
    <h1>{{car.id}}</h1>
</div>
```

This will prevent angular from accessing child elements of cars array in case it is empty.

Another way to get rid of it would be to use a conditional render method. Simply add an if loop for the block rendering the cars data to render only if length of cars array is greater than zero. For instance,

```
<div ngIf="cars.length > 0">
    <h1>{{cars[0].id}}</h1>
</div>
```

Although, this is something, I'm saying without having a proper look at your template file. Do let me know if this helps or if there's anything else I can help with